# "Compile Error" with array-reference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compilation

this is my first post on here, so please be gentle if I missed anything or screwed up.

I've been working on an Excel-Tool in Excel 2010 and am currently testing if it also works in Excel 2013. 
Most of it works all fine, but I got one small Problem that confuses me. When I open the file in 2013, enter some data and test it, it runs smoothly; but when I go back to 2010 to use the same file I get the message "Compile Error: Can't Find Project or Library."

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Label1_Click()

If Application.Sum([ci_pke_cfbiat]) < 0 Then
     MsgBox ("With the current numbers, Excel won't be able to calcualte a   valid IRR.")
End If

Call IRRcalculation(Me.Name)

Call Paybackcalculation(Me.Name)

End Sub
```

The highlighted part of the code after I hit the "debug" button is the array reference "[ci_pke_cfbiat]". Now I already did some research on that matter and looked into the references on both 2010 and 2013, and found that under Excel 2010 it says "MISSING: Microsoft PowerPoint 15.0 Object Library". When I deactivated that reference all works as it is supposed to. What I don't understand is why a PowerPoint-Library would cause a problem for my array-references?

Also, is there some "easy" way to solve this problem; easier than manually turning that library off everytime I open a file from 2013 in 2010? I already tried some things in the code like using "VBA." instead of "Application." and similar, but that didn't work.

Again sorry if I did anything wrong, and I hope this topic hasn't been discussed somewhere else already; I couldn't find anything related that was really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has to do with how you bind, see [early binding vs late binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/245115) for more information.

Comment: Its 2 am and I am mobile so no code. But all you need to do is use late binding. Search google with excel Vba power point late binding.